# Как переключить раскладку клавиатуры из хрома?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

В html форме есть 2 инпута, в один вводится текст на английском, в другой на русском. Напрягает постоянно переключать раскладку. Подскажите, где посмотреть апи для переключения раскладки программным способом (javascript).

Comment: Просто интересно: а как переключается раскладка на клавиатурах где нет кириллицы?

Comment: Вероятнее всего это невозможно.

Answer (score 2):

Переключить язык из js нельзя никак. Можно попробовать сделать что-то типа эмуляции переключения, то есть заменять значения для определенных кейкодов на русские или наоборот английские. В примере я сделал словари только для букв, по такому же принципу можно сделать для остальных кнопок.

**Такая реализация имеет место быть только для каких-то личных проектов, то есть если вы на 100% уверены, что у каждого пользователя есть и латиница и кириллица.**

**При такой реализации на публичных проектах пользователи, у которых нет кириллицы скорее всего захотят встретиться и поговорить с Вами лично)**

```js
const ruInput = document.querySelector('#ru');
const enInput = document.querySelector('#en');

const ruKeyCodes = {
  81: 'й',
  87: 'ц',
  69: 'у',
  82: 'к',
  84: 'е',
  89: 'н',
  85: 'г',
  73: 'ш',
  79: 'щ',
  80: 'з',
  219: 'х',
  221: 'ъ',
  65: 'ф',
  83: 'ы',
  68: 'в',
  70: 'а',
  71: 'п',
  72: 'р',
  74: 'о',
  75: 'л',
  76: 'д',
  186: 'ж',
  222: 'э',
  90: 'я',
  88: 'ч',
  67: 'с',
  86: 'м',
  66: 'и',
  78: 'т',
  77: 'ь',
  188: 'б',
  190: 'ю',
  192: 'ё'
};

const enKeyCodes = {
  81: 'q',
  87: 'w',
  69: 'e',
  82: 'r',
  84: 't',
  89: 'y',
  85: 'u',
  73: 'i',
  79: 'o',
  80: 'p',
  65: 'a',
  83: 's',
  68: 'd',
  70: 'f',
  71: 'g',
  72: 'h',
  74: 'j',
  75: 'k',
  76: 'l',
  90: 'z',
  88: 'x',
  67: 'c',
  86: 'v',
  66: 'b',
  78: 'n',
  77: 'm'
};

ruInput.addEventListener('keydown', (evt) => { 
  if(evt.keyCode in ruKeyCodes){
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.currentTarget.value += ruKeyCodes[evt.keyCode];
  }
});

enInput.addEventListener('keydown', (evt) => { 
  if(evt.keyCode in enKeyCodes){
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.currentTarget.value += enKeyCodes[evt.keyCode];
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="ru" id="ru" placeholder="Только русский"/>
<input type="text" name="en" id="en" placeholder="Only english"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Это только как маленький эксперимент**,
надо дорабатывать(например с символами где нет кириллицы).

`setRangeText` и `setSelectionRange` используем для замены при выделении текста.

```js
'use strict';

var map = {
    ru: [ "й", "ц", "у", "к", "е", "н", "г", "ш", "щ", "з", "х", "ъ", "ф", "ы", "в", "а", "п", "р", "о", "л", "д", "ж", "э", "я", "ч", "с", "м", "и", "т", "ь", "б", "ю" ],
    en: [ "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p", "[", "]", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", ";", "'", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", "." ]
};

var ru = document.getElementById( 'ru' );
var en = document.getElementById( 'en' );

ru.__lang = [ 'ru', 'en' ];
en.__lang = [ 'en', 'ru' ];

ru.addEventListener( 'keydown', setInputText );
en.addEventListener( 'keydown', setInputText );

function setInputText ( e ) {
    var i, k = e.key,
            start = this.selectionStart,
            end = this.selectionEnd;

    if ( ( i = map[this.__lang[1]].indexOf( k ) ) !== -1 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setRangeText( map[this.__lang[0]][i], start, end );
        this.setSelectionRange( start + 1, start + 1 );
    }
    else if ( ( i = map[this.__lang[1]].indexOf( k.toLowerCase() ) ) !== -1 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setRangeText( map[this.__lang[0]][i].toUpperCase(), start, end );
        this.setSelectionRange( start + 1, start + 1 );
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>keyboard-layout</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            input {
                display: block;
                width: 300px;
                margin: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Keyboard layout</h1>
        <label for="ru">ru</label>
        <input type="text" id="ru">
        <label for="en">en</label>
        <input type="text" id="en">
        <script src="keyboard-layout.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```