# ghbdtn => привет. Перевод с английского регистра на русский

Tags: javascript

Пишу бота для дословного перевода сообщений с английского на русский. Хотелось бы узнать об общепринятых решениях этой задачи, а не придумывать велосипед как обычно.

Comment: Создайте файлик, в котором символу на русском будет соответствовать символ на английском, json к примеру, заполните из него map и заменяйте текст таким образом, используя map-у

Comment: Какое отношение замена символов имеет к дословному переводу? @LexMarchenko

Comment: @Эникейщик, я написал то, о чём был вопрос. К вопросу - прямое.

Comment: @Эникейщик, думаю, вопрос был о транслитерации, а не о переводе.

Comment: @eanmos, транслитерация - это когда  `привет` → `privet` или `privet` → `привет`. А тут, что то типа *сменить раскладку*.

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/948326/256824

Comment: @РустамГимранов, хм, точно. Сейчас откачу.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

```js
let en = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./`QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"ZXCVBNM<>?~&"
let ru = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю.ёЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,Ё?";

let alphabet = {}
for( let i = 0; i < en.length; i++ ){
  alphabet[en[i]] = ru[i];
} /* Так легче сделать объект, чем вручную всё записывать.
     Окончательный вариант уже можно прописать в виде обычного объекта. */

console.log( JSON.stringify( alphabet ) );

let jin = document.getElementById('jin');
let jout = document.getElementById('jout');

jin.addEventListener('input', function(){
  jout.innerHTML = toRussianStr( this.value );
});

function toRussianStr(str){
  return str.replace(/\S/g, function(match){
    /* \S в регулярных выражениях - совпадает с любым символом кроме пробельных.
     * Совпадение передается функции, через переменную match
     * А функция возвращает перевод, если такой есть... 
     * || ИЛИ тот же символ - красным, если он не найден.  
     */
    return alphabet[match] || '<span style="color: red;">' + match + '</span>';
  });
}

jout.innerHTML = toRussianStr(jin.value);
```

```html
<textarea id="jin">ghbdtn vbh!</textarea>
<div id="jout"></div>
```

Comment: Это не перевод, а замена символов.

Comment: @Эникейщик что и требовалось автору ( в заглавлении ghbdtn → привет ). Только формулирвку надо подобрать)